# A inequality proposed at Zhautykov Olympiad 2008

Tags: inequality, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, tangent-line-method

An inequality proposed at Zhautykov Olympiad 2008.

> Let be $a,b,c >0$ with $abc=1$. Prove that: 
>   $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{1}{(a+b)b}} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$$

Set $a=\frac{x}{y}$, $b=\frac{y}{z}$, $c=\frac{z}{x}$.

Our inequality becomes:
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{z^2}{zx+y^2}} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$$ 
Now we use that: $z^2+x^2 \geq 2zx.$
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{z^2}{zx+y^2}} \geq \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{2z^2}{z^2+x^2+2y^2}} \geq \frac{3}{2}.$$

Now applying Cauchy-Schwarz we obtain the desired result.

What I wrote can be found on this link: [mateforum](http://www.mateforum.ro/viewtopic.php?t=925).
But now, I don't know how to apply Cauchy-Schwarz.

Thanks:)

Comment: What is the notation $\sum_{cyc}$?

Comment: Tell me if this is where you get stuck: If $S$ is the last sum you have above, then using Cauchy-Schwarz you can obtain the inequality
$$\tfrac{1}{2}S(4x^2 + 4y^2 + 4z^2) \ge (x + y + z)^2.$$
What's disturbing about this is that you then get $S \ge \tfrac{1}{2} (x + y + z)^2/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)$. It would be natural then to try to prove that $(x + y + z)^2 / (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \ge 3$, but instead the reverse is true; $(x + y + z)^2 / (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) \le 3$.

Comment: @daniel, the summation is cyclic, so the full summation is
$$\frac{1}{(a+b)b} +\frac{1}{(b+c)c} + \frac{1}{(a+c)a}$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\mathrm{LHS}$ of last inequality is homogeneous we can assume $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Then it becomes
$$
\mathrm{LHS} = 2\sum_{cyc} \frac {x^2} {1 + z^2} =:2I
$$
Now using **Cauchy-Schwarz inequality** we get
$$
1 = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = \left(\sum_{cyc} x\sqrt{1 + z^2} \cdot \frac x {\sqrt{1 + z^2}}\right)^2 \leq\\
\left(\sum_{cyc} x^2(1 + z^2)\right) \cdot \left( \sum_{cyc} \frac {x^2}{1 + z^2} \right) = I \cdot \sum_{cyc} x^2(1 + z^2)
$$
To finish, let's note that **CS inequality** implies
$$
x^2\cdot z^2 + y^2 \cdot x^2 + z^2 \cdot y^2 \leq x^4 + y^4 + z^4
$$
and therefore
$$
\sum_{cyc} x^2(1 + z^2) = 1 + x^2 z^2 + y^2 x^2 + z^2 y^2 \leq 1 + \frac {(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2} 3 = \frac 4 3
$$

Comment: I have a question :) How do you know to apply the relation of  homogenity and how do you apply it ? Why $x^2+y^2+z^2=1? $ Thanks :)

Comment: @Iuli Since $\mathrm{LHS}(x, y, z) = \mathrm{LHS}(kx, ky, kz)$, if the inequality holds for $(x, y, z)$, it holds for each $(kx, ky, kz)$ with $k > 0$. So, for example, if you want to prove the inequality for $(x, y, z)$, it is sufficient you prove it for $(kx, ky, kz)$ with $k = 1/\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ and that is equivalent to assume the condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$. Of course, you are free to choose other values for $k$ and therefore other conditions on $(x, y, z)$. $k = 1/\sqrt[3]{abc}$, for example, is equivalent to the condition $abc=1$. (continue)

Comment: @Iuli I used the condition $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ because I felt it would have simplified the structure of the inequality and (overall) reduced the amount of symbols to write. However, the line of the proof remains the same also without the above assumption.

Comment: There are a number of proofs for that inequality (with explanations) at http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h183916p1010959

Answer (score 5):

Here is a very short one.

Suppose w.l.o.g. $a \ge b \ge c$. Then by the rearrangement inequality,

$$
S = \frac{1}{(a+b)b} +\frac{1}{(b+c)c} + \frac{1}{(a+c)a} \ge \frac{1}{(a+b)c} +\frac{1}{(b+c)a} + \frac{1}{(a+c)b}  = T
$$

So

$$
2 S \ge S + T = \frac{b+c}{(a+b)bc} +\frac{c+a}{(b+c)ca} + \frac{a+b}{(a+c)ab} \geq 3 \Big( \frac{1}{abc} \Big)^{2/3} = 3
$$
which proves it, where in the last step AM-GM was used.

Comment: Technically, one cannot assume $a\geq b\geq c$ as the expression is not symmetric. I would say no matter the ordering of $a,b,c$, $S\geq T$ due to rearrangement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a=\frac{x}{y}$ and $b=\frac{y}{z}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ be positives.

Hence, since $abc=1$, we get $c=\frac{z}{x}$ and by C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(a+b)b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{z^2}{xz+y^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{z^4}{xz^3+z^2y^2}\geq\frac{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^3y)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that
$$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\geq3\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2y^2+x^3y)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4-3x^3y+x^2y^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)x^2(2x-y)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left((x-y)x^2(2x-y)-\frac{x^4-y^4}{4}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(7x^2+2xy+y^2)\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: Nice trick on the penultimate line.

Comment: As an aside, expanding the "remains to prove" results in $ \sum 2x^2 + \sum x^2y^2 \geq 3 \sum x^3 y$, which is true by AM-GM.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes, I agree. Thank you for your interest!