# Olympiad inequality: is this reasoning sound?

Tags: logic, inequality, proof-verification

I am trying to show that for $a,b,c>0,\;abc=1:$

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{b(a+b)}+\frac{1}{c(b+c)}+\frac{1}{a(c+a)}}_{X}\geq \frac{3}{2}$$

This problem is from the Zhautykov Olympiad of 2008.

**Attempt:**

If $X\geq \frac{3}{2}$ is satisfied for all $a,b,c$ satisfying the initial conditions then by letting $a\mapsto b$ and $b\mapsto a$, the following inequality must also be satisfied:

$$\underbrace{\frac{1}{a(a+b)}+\frac{1}{b(b+c)}+\frac{1}{c(c+a)}}_{Y}\geq\frac{3}{2}$$

The reasoning can be reversed, thus $X\geq\frac{3}{2}\iff Y\geq\frac{3}{2}$. Now, in any case:

$$X+Y=\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{bc}+\frac{1}{ca}\geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(abc)^2}}=3$$

By AM-GM. Hence either $X\geq \frac{3}{2}$ or $Y\geq \frac{3}{2}$ is true, and therefore they are both true.

Is this logic valid? It seems too easy.

Comment: can you tell me what is the meaning of $\sum_{\text{cyc}}$

Comment: @miracle173 You sum the elements *cyclically*.

Comment: The number $c$ doesn't appear in the sum?

Comment: $\sum_{\text{cyc}} f(a,b,c)=f(a,b,c)+f(b,c,a)+f(c,a,b)$ includes your definition.

Comment: same question: [A inequality proposed at Zhautykov Olympiad 2008](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202053/a-inequality-proposed-at-zhautykov-olympiad-2008)

Comment: @miracle173 This is not the same question: I am not asking for a solution, I am asking whether my logic is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Write $X$ as $X=f(a,b,c)$. Then $Y=f(b,a,c)$. What you are saying first is
$${\rm if}\;\; \left(\forall a,b,c\;:\; f(a,b,c)\geq\frac32\right)\;\;{\rm then}\;\; \left(\forall a,b,c\;:\; f(b,a,c)\geq \frac 32\right) $$
which is quite correct.

Then what you show is
$$\forall a,b,c\;:\; \left( f(a,b,c)\geq\frac32\;\;{\rm or}\;\; f(b,a,c)\geq\frac32\right) $$

But here you are in trouble: one cannot interchange the $\forall$ and the "or" without any further information.

Answer (score 2):

No, your reasoning is wrong. The inequality

$$X+Y \geq 3$$ is ok. But you did not proof that if $ a,b,c \gt 0 \land   abc=1 \land X(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$ for a special triple $(a,b,c)$ then $Y(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$ for the same triple (and vice versa) but you only proved that if $ a,b,c \gt 0 \land   abc=1 \land X(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$ **for all**  triples $(a,b,c)$ then $Y(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$ (and vice versa) which is only a change in notation. So you assume $X(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$ to prove $X(a,b,c) \ge \frac{3}{2}$