# Interesting 3 Variable Inequality for Real Numbers

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I recently saw an olympiad style inequality that seemed very difficult. I tried to use elementary inequalities such as AM-GM or Cauchy-Schwarz, but neither have helped in making significant progress. Could anyone provide a rigorous proof, preferably using more elementary inequalities?

**Problem:** "Prove the inequality $\frac{1}{y(x+y)}+\frac{1}{z(y+z)}+\frac{1}{x(z+x)}\geq\frac{27}{2(x+y+z)^2}$ if $x,y,z$ are positive reals."

Comment: Aggregating the left side seems painful

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is homogenous in $(x, y, z)$, therefore we can assume
that $xyz=1$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{y(x+y)}+\frac{1}{z(y+z)}+\frac{1}{x(z+x)} \ge \dfrac{3}{2}
$$
as for example demonstrated in
[If $xyz=1$, prove $\frac{1}{y(x+y)}+\frac{1}{z(y+z)}+\frac{1}{x(z+x)} \geqslant \frac{3}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937941/if-xyz-1-prove-frac1yxy-frac1zyz-frac1xzx-geqslant) or [A inequality proposed at Zhautykov Olympiad 2008](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202053/a-inequality-proposed-at-zhautykov-olympiad-2008).

Also
$$
 1 = \sqrt[3]{xyz} \le \frac{x+y+z}3 \Longrightarrow
 (x+y+z)^2 \ge 9 \, .
$$
from the inequality between the geometric and the arithmetic mean.

Combining these estimates gives the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

This follows almost immediately by a direct application of Hölder's inequality (generalised Cauchy-Schwarz):

$$\begin{aligned} \left ( \sum \limits_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{y(x+y)} \right ) (y + z + x) ((x+y) + (y+z) + (z+x)) &\geq (1^{\frac{1}{3}} + 1^{\frac{1}{3}} + 1^{\frac{1}{3}})^{3}\\
\iff \sum \limits_{\text{cyc}} \frac{1}{y(x+y)} &\geq \frac{27}{(x+y+z)(2x+2y+2z)}\\
&= \frac{27}{2(x+y+z)^2}\\
\end{aligned}$$